# Keyboard backlight not working: Acer Aspire R13 R7-372T

Tags: laptop, keyboard, acer-aspire, backlight

I recently bought an Acer Aspire R13 R7-372T Laptop. I noticed that the keyboard backlight was never on. I tried the keyboard shortcut to increase the backlight brightness but to no avail. I tried that on the pre-installed Windows 10 and also on Ubuntu 16.10.

How do I debug the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the keyboard shipped with the laptop was broken. I contacted the vendor and send them the laptop and they replaced the keyboard.